# Where do I store a function that acts on an array of objects?

Tags: function, class, simulation, particles

I'm trying to create something like the following using c++:

[image]

I have a class called **particle** which will store the position, velocity of each particle. Additionally, a member function will update the particle's position using velocity data.

I'm also trying to write a function that will detect a collision between particles and the boundaries of the box. To do so, this function needs access to each particle's position and velocity. Thus, the function needs to take an entire array of particles as a parameter. However, this function can't exist as a member function of the particle class, because then it won't have access to all the particles.

Question: **Where do I include the collision detection function, such that it is an extensible part of the particle class?**

I thought about just writing this function inside my main.cpp file, but I haven't the slightest clue whether this adheres to the OOP guidelines. Ideally there might be other functions that also act on an array of particles.

Comment: Whatever "owns" the particles would likely be the place to put particle collision detection. In this case, whatever owns the particle list and is responsible for managing them. (and +1 for the most in-your-face sample of what you're trying to do I've seen in a question in a long time).

Comment: Extensible in what way? The "obvious" answer is a static member function, but it might depend on the role of this `particle` class (principally, is it designed for use as a base class or not), and how you want to represent the bounding box. Also be aware that a lot of C++ code (perhaps the majority), and almost all of the C++ standard libraries, are designed *without* following OOP guidelines. C++ allows for other programming paradigms than just OOP.

Comment: Also a +1 for the GIF!

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is some sort of "ParticleContainer" object, that holds the array of particles, and performs operations on the particle system as a whole.

(That's also where you would put the code that runs down the array and calls the "Draw" functions.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that good idea will be to declare a detection function as a friend of class particle: it will have access to all members in class. Then you can fire this function in loop inside of some kind of manager function that will calculate the collision to all particles in array. In this

```
void CollisionMgr(particleClass *ParticleArrayPtr, int NumOfParticles)
{
   while(NumOfParticles)

    {
      CollisionOfParticle(*ParticleArrayPtr, NumOfParticles);
      NumOfParticles--;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a pattern along these lines: Keep all the model state in a single class called `Model`or `Environment`; have a separate class `Renderer` which knows how to draw the model state; have a `System` class which ties these together. The following is highly abbreviated, but hopefully gives the idea:

```
class Box {};

class Location {};

class Particle
{
public:
    void updatePosition(double dt);
    const Location& getLocation();
};

class Environment
{
public:
    void checkForCollisions();
private:
    Box box;
    std::vector<Particle> particles;
};

class Renderer
{
public:
    void render(Environment& environment);
};

class System
{
    Environment environment;
    Renderer renderer;
};
```